# Воспроизведение hd-DVD и Blue-ray на Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu

Привет!

В линуксе я чайник, не умею ничего! Но хотелось бы узнать, можно ли воспроизвести hd-DVD и Blue-ray в linux! В Винде без проблем проигрывается через kmp hd-DVD и Blue-ray  размером в 40Гб, nVidia with CUDA. Можно ли установить необходимые кодеки и плееры без танца с консолью? Спасибо.

Comment: [Playing Blu-Ray and HD DVD Video](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/BluRayAndHDDVD).

Answer (score 1):

Да возможно. Поставьте smplayer с ним скорее всего все заработает, либо vlc.